# "Next Without For" on a IF Statement in VBA

Tags: vba, loops

I am trying to verify that there are no error between the value in cells on column A and in Column C.
I keep getting an error saying "Next Without For"

```
Sub ISIN()

Dim i As Integer
Dim y As Integer
Dim t As Integer
Dim z As Integer
For i = 20 To 53
For y = 6 To 38
For t = 20 To 53
For z = 53 To 87
If Cells(i, 3) = Cells(y, 1) Then
Cells(t, 19) = "Abracadabra"
Else: Cells(z, 3) = Cells(y, 1)
Next z
Next t
Next y
Next i
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: If you indent your code it will be much easier to see how your code blocks line up. The standard is 4 spaces for each indent level.

Comment: Endif ... its in wrong place.

Answer (score 1):

you need to close the if statement before you can use the next keyword

```
Sub ISIN()

Dim i As Integer
Dim y As Integer
Dim t As Integer
Dim z As Integer
 For i = 20 To 53
  For y = 6 To 38
   For t = 20 To 53
    For z = 53 To 87
     If Cells(i, 3) = Cells(y, 1) Then
      Cells(t, 19) = "Abracadabra"
     Else
      Cells(z, 3) = Cells(y, 1)
     end if
   Next z
  Next t
 Next y
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. it worked at first but now is teloing me that the code execution as been interupted. Ever seen that?

Comment: at which line occurs this message?

Comment: The seconf line. And if I click on Debug it tells me something is wrong with "End if".

Comment: what does it say exactly?

Comment: Just "Code execution has been interrupted"

Comment: try the methods recommended in this msdn thread, https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3a5cf3ab-fe20-45d5-912c-bbb249b1e391/code-execution-has-been-interrupted?forum=isvvba
I don't remember if I ever had this issue

Comment: Now it works, but i keeps running in circles and never gives me an answer